# Replace text in values from dropdowns in razor statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a HTML form with some dropdowns. I need the values of the selected item in the dropdowns to replace tags from another dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TrainID, new SelectList(Model.TrainItems, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "train" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReasonID, new SelectList(Model.ReasonItems, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "reason" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MessageID, new SelectList(Model.MessageItems, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "message" })
```

I need the values of the train and the reason selected by the user to replace certain parts of the message item selected.

For example, the message selected would say: "Train # [NUM] has been cancelled due to [REASON]. We apologize for the inconvenience." And then it would dynamically populate the message with the selected values from the first two dropdowns into a textbox on the HTML form: "Train # 123 has been cancelled due to weather. We apologize for the inconvenience.":

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnnouncementText, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "text" } })
```

I've tried to do this through javascript with no luck:

```
$(function () {
    var str = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace("[REASON]", model.ReasonName);
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = res;
});
```

Clearly, the string.replace method isn't meant for razor statements and I'm wondering if there is a such a method or if I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: replace model.ReasonName with document.getElementById('reason').value

Comment: @RajN that might work, but is there something else to add to update the form and pull the replaced message into the textbox once the message is selected in the dropdown?

Comment: u mean how to trigger the replacement function on dropdown selection?

Comment: @RajN yes, is that through an onchange call?

Comment: yes, use $('#reason').on('change', function () { ... }

Comment: @RajN thank you for all your help! I have one more question, why is the document.getElementById('reason').value giving me the id number of the selection rather than the value?

Comment: If you want to get the display text, you should use $("#reason option:selected").text();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help, I was able to find the answer that worked best for me. I was really close with my first attempt and with a few tweaks was able to get it.

```
$('#message').on('change', function () {
var selection = $.trim($("#message :selected").text()));
var str = document.getElementById("reason");
var reason = str.option[str.selectedIndex].text;
var res = selection.replace("[REASON]", reason);
$('#text').val(res); 
});
```

Thank you to RajN for the help!